# How to catch 405 Method Not Found in jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, webservice-client, jqxhr

I'm trying to catch if the website is accidentally making a cross domain call (for example if the user types the IP in the url instead of the domain.  (This is a commercial, installable app so I don't have IIS control to set up any forwarding, etc.).  This doesn't work:

```
                error: function (x, e) {
                    // If the web service failed for any of the reasons below, then we
                    // call the custom error dialog display function with the response
                    // text passed back from the erro
                    if (x.status === 405) {
                       alert("405 error")
                    } 
                }
```

Is there any way in javascript to catch the 405 error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) method?